# Launching a mp4 file through vlc in java

Tags: java, mp4, vlc

When I tried:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("vlc /home/user/a.mp4");
```

Nothing happened.
Can anyone say why?

Comment: You should see an excpetion message when you run it from the console. What is the wording fo this message? Could be something similar to `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "vlc" ...` The part of the `...` is the important one.

Comment: @Ram did you try my solution? Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes it worked Thanks a lot@idos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your specific line of code, I think you should try:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/path/to/vlc", "/home/user/a.mp4" });
```

As a side note, if your system supports it, I would consider using the [Desktop Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html):

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("/home/user/a.mp4"));
}
```

(You need to have the GNOME libraries installed so Java will recognize it)